# Array through parameter by reference affecting another array

Tags: c#, parameters, undefined-behavior

CardDetails is a Structure.

```
public static void ParceIntricaciesJabber(ref CardDetails[] WhichArray) 
{
  WhichArray[0].ID = 50;
  WhichArray[0].Type = "None";
}
```

In calling:

```
ParceIntricaciesJabber(ref OpponentCards);
```

After I call the function though, another Array called PlayerCards is affected in the exact same way as OpponentCards - despite being declared as two different arrays. They have the same number of elements and the same data Type, and that's it.

This probably should be obvious but i'm not seeing it. The code works in VB.NET. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Initialization Code:

```
public static class Module1{

  public static CardDetails[] PlayerCards = new CardDetails[100];
  public static CardDetails[] OpponentCards = new CardDetails[100];

}
```

And also when navigating to the Form

```
for (int n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
        {
            Module1.PlayerCards[n] = new CardDetails();
            Module1.OpponentCards[n] = new CardDetails();
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to by using `ref`?  That's your problem.

Comment: Removing ref didn't do anything :(

Comment: How do you instantiate the two arrays?

Comment: You need to provide more code. Chances are you are pointing array one at array two assuming it will copy the content.

Comment: Alright, I edited with more code

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* example - we can't see what `CardDetails` looks like at the moment. (The fact that apparently it's a mutable structure rings alarm bells - it shouldn't affect this, but it's a generally bad idea.) Also, please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html to learn what `ref` does.

Comment: Oh, and arrays start at 0 - currently I'd expect your final code block to blow up when `n` reaches 100.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are sharing the reference to the arrays. Even though it is structs inside the array, the array itself is a reference type. You will need to post your array instantiation code to verify one way or the other though